# How to I customize the CSS of an embedded Instagram image

Tags: css, iframe, instagram, embed, customization

I would like to achieve a CSS customization whereby I have to write my own CSS to overwrite some of the CSS that comes default  when you embed an Instagram picture.

He default CSS looks like this
[Default look of Instagram embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nc5C.png)

I would it to look something like the customization I saw on Harvard website
[Targeted look: e.g Harvard website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo9ea.png)

When I write my own CSS using default class names, it is not getting the precedence over the default therefore not overwriting it.

How can I achieve it as Harvard did?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, and ideally a working demo. Thanks

Comment: Add your styles after the instagram style (if they are of the same specificity) or make your rules more specific - eg wrap the image in an element with a class that you can target.  Have a read of this, may help you understand a bit more: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/